# How can i get a file name size in bytes and then reportprogress?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the top of `form1` i have a string array and a string file name:

```
string[] stringProgressReport = new string[4];
string FileName = "";
```

Then in `openfiledialog` I'm getting the `FileName`.

Then I have two events:

```
private void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video obj)
{
    stringProgressReport[0] = obj.Status.UploadStatus;
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, 0);
}
```

And

```
private void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress obj)
{
    stringProgressReport[1] = obj.Status.ToString();
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, 1);
    double mbSent = ((double)obj.BytesSent) / (1 << 20);
    stringProgressReport[2] = mbSent.ToString();
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, 2);
    double percentComplete = ((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100;
    stringProgressReport[3] = percentComplete.ToString();
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, 3);
}
```

`totalBytes` should be the file size in bytes if i'm not wrong with the calculation of the `percentComplete`.

Then, in the end, I have a `backgroundworker1_progresschanged` event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int eventIndex = (int)e.UserState;

    if (eventIndex == 0)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = stringProgressReport[0];
    }
    else
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = stringProgressReport[1];
    }
}
```

When I reported progress two items from the `stringProgressReport` in the two events it was working fine.

But now, what should I do with the `IF` in the `backgroundworker1_progresschanged` event when reporting 4 items ?

And how do I calculate the `percentComplete` and getting the file size in bytes ?

Getting the file size in bytes. I think I got it. I'm doing:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(FileName))
{
    totalBytes = fileStream.Length;
}
```

`totalBytes` is a type `long` and global.
And I'm doing this in the `openfiledialog` right after selecting a file.

If this part is fine, now I need to solve the second problem.

I tried now in the `backgroundworker_progresschanged` to add this line in the `ELSE`:

```
toolStripProgressBar1.Value = Int32.Parse(stringProgressReport[3]);
```

But I'm getting the following exception on this line:

`FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format`

```
System.FormatException occurred
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
       at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
       at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
       at Youtube_Manager.Form1.backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(Object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\Form1.cs:line 313
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the way you are reporting is a bit unusual to say the least.  But if I try to follow your pattern, then your `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` will probably want to change to something like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int eventIndex = (int)e.UserState;

    if (eventIndex == 0) // upload status.
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = stringProgressReport[0];
    }
    else if (eventIndex == 1) // obj.Status
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = stringProgressReport[1];
    }
    else if (eventIndex == 2) // mb sent so far
    {
        // ??? where do you want to put this ??? = stringProgressReport[2];
    }
    else if (eventIndex == 3) // percent complete
    {
        toolStripProgressBar1.Value = Int32.Parse(stringProgressReport[3]);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid event index: " + eventIndex);
    }
}
```

And then, to address your second question: the reason why `toolStripProgressBar1.Value = Int32.Parse(stringProgressReport[3]);` throws a `FormatException` is because you are trying to format a decimal.  Since you want to use this as an integer, I suggest fixing these 2 lines:

```
double percentComplete = ((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100;
stringProgressReport[3] = percentComplete.ToString();
```

... by changing them to this instead to make sure you do actually have an integer:

```
int percentComplete = (int)Math.Round(((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100);
stringProgressReport[3] = percentComplete.ToString();
```

Comment: sstan it's working untill when it's getting to 100% then i'm getting exception on the line: int eventIndex = (int)e.UserState; InvalidCastException: pecified cast is not valid and when i'm watching on UserState i see 4 indexs and index number 3 value is 100. Maybe it's not possible to cast int if it's int already ?

Comment: System.InvalidCastException occurred
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=Youtube-Manager
  StackTrace:
       at Youtube_Manager.Form1.backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(Object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\Form1.cs:line 306
  InnerException:

Comment: is `stringProgressReport[3] = percentComplete.ToString();` the only place where you set `stringProgressReport[3]`?  Or is there some other line of code you haven't posted that sets it to 100?

Comment: wait a second, which line is giving you the error?  Is it: `int eventIndex = (int)e.UserState;`?  If so, then it has nothing to do with the percentage.  What is the value of `e.UserState` when it crashes?

Comment: In e.UserState where i get the exception i see on index 0 the string "uploaded" on index 1 i see "Completed" on index 2 i see "25.1234407424927" and on index 3 i see "100"

Comment: The value is 0 so it's the first index "uploaded"

Comment: I think we are getting confused.  Where are you seeing index 0, 1, 2, 3, etc...?  `e.UserState` should be a single number.  If it isn't, then it will give you a InvalidCastException.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80958/discussion-between-sstan-and-simon-gamlieli).